# Webscraper with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

All right, guys? I have a question related to Web-scrapers in python. I was working on one for this specific site https://www.cadastroindustrialmg.com.br:449/industria/Setor

As I don’t have much experience with this, I’m a little lost. Because, what I want requires many “clicks” and redirection to different pages. For example, go to a “category” then to a “subcategory” to be able to go to a “company” then get an “email” and write all this in a separate file and do this infinitely.
Could someone give me some light? I tried to make a request to try to get a JSON file with all the information, but I also had no success.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links():
  """Obtém a lista de links das empresas."""
  response = requests.get("https://www.cadastroindustrialmg.com.br:449/industria/Setor")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
  links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "btn btn-primary"})
  return [link["href"] for link in links]

def get_email(link):
  """Extrai o email da página."""
  response = requests.get(link)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
  email = soup.find("div", {"class": "contato"}).find("a").get("href").partition("mailto:")[2]
  return email

def save_email(email):
  """Salva o email em um arquivo."""
  with open("emails.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(email + "\n")

links = get_links()
for link in links:
  email = get_email(link)
  save_email(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach it will be:

- Use the filterded search to get all the industries.
  [https://www.cadastroindustrialmg.com.br:449/industria/resultadobusca?Filters=&K=Produção](https://www.cadastroindustrialmg.com.br:449/industria/resultadobusca?Filters=&K=Produ%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- Get the url for each one.
  (/industria/index/52ffef6c-59f8-4caa-a59a-c39da192f83c, ...)
- Get the next page selector or just request the next page with a loop.
  [https://www.cadastroindustrialmg.com.br:449/industria/resultadobusca?K=Produção&Page=2&Filters=](https://www.cadastroindustrialmg.com.br:449/industria/resultadobusca?K=Produ%C3%A7%C3%A3o&Page=2&Filters=)
- Get all info inside the page crawled.
- Append the new info to a dictionary object
- At the end write to a file

**Make sure you can crawl that domain without legal liability**